# Read user input from multiple threads simultaneously

Tags: c, multithreading, user-input

I am trying to create a program that can create a thread, do things in the thread (specifically user input and file writing), and simultaneously wait for user input in main to cancel the thread. I have everything working in this program except for the simultaneous reading.

Currently when I try to create the thread it just does the while loop in main and when i type quit it quickly prints the first print statement in the thread and then exits the thread. I would like the scanf in main and in the thread to work simultaneously.

```
#include "../VNA/C/Linux_macOS/pre_Prog/file.h"

#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define handle_error(ret, msg)                                                 \
  do {                                                                         \
    errno = ret;                                                               \
    perror(msg);                                                               \
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                        \
  } while (0)

atomic_bool exit_flag = 0;


static void *read_prof(void *arg) {
  FILE *profdat = NULL;
  fpos_t *prof_start = NULL;
  fpos_t *prof_end = NULL;
  int profile;
  int points;
  char *chan = NULL;
  bool chan_flag = 0;
  char *chan_num = NULL;
  int interval;
  char *testtype = NULL;
  int testtime;
  int calk;
  bool timed_flag = 0;
  bool clean_chan, clean_testtype, clean_chan_num,
      clean_prof_start, clean_prof_end = 0;
  pthread_cleanup_push(free, prof_start);
  pthread_cleanup_push(free, prof_end);
  pthread_cleanup_push(free, chan);
  pthread_cleanup_push(free, testtype);
  pthread_cleanup_push(free, chan_num);
  prof_start = malloc(sizeof(fpos_t));
  if (prof_start == NULL)
    goto fail;

  prof_end = malloc(sizeof(fpos_t));
  if (prof_end == NULL)
    goto fail;

  chan = malloc(4);
  if (chan == NULL)
    goto fail;

  chan_num = malloc(5);
  if (chan_num == NULL)
    goto fail;

  testtype = malloc(5);
  if (testtype == NULL)
    goto fail;

  printf("Select profile:");
  scanf("%d", &profile);

  profdat = fopen("profiles_data", "r");
  if (profdat == NULL)
    goto fail;
  find_prof(profdat, profile, prof_start, prof_end);

  fsetpos(profdat, prof_start);

  fscanf(profdat, "%d", &points);
  fscanf(profdat, "%s", chan);
  if (strcmp(chan, "ONE") == 0) {
    chan_flag = 1;
    fscanf(profdat, "%s", chan_num);
  }
  fscanf(profdat, "%s", testtype);
  fscanf(profdat, "%d", &interval);
  if (strcmp(testtype, "TIMED") == 0) {
    timed_flag = 1;
    fscanf(profdat, "%d", &testtime);
  }
  fscanf(profdat, "%d", &calk);

  printf("points:%d\n", points);
  printf("chan:%s\n", chan);
  if (chan_flag)
    printf("chan_num:%s\n", chan_num);
  printf("testtype:%s\n", testtype);
  printf("interval:%d\n", interval);
  if (timed_flag)
    printf("testtime:%d\n", testtime);
  printf("calk:%d\n", calk);

  while (!exit_flag) {
    pthread_testcancel();
    sleep(60 * interval);
  }
    fclose(profdat);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
fail:
    fclose(profdat);
  pthread_cleanup_pop(clean_chan_num);
  pthread_cleanup_pop(clean_testtype);
  pthread_cleanup_pop(clean_chan);
  pthread_cleanup_pop(clean_prof_end);
  pthread_cleanup_pop(clean_prof_start);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main(void) {
  int ret = 0;
  pthread_t thr;
  char *detect = NULL;

  ret = pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &read_prof, NULL);
  if (ret != 0)
    handle_error(ret, "pthread_create");

  detect = malloc(64);
  if (detect == NULL) {
    perror("memory error");
    goto fail;
  }
  while (!exit_flag) {
    scanf("%s", detect);
    if (strcmp(detect, "quit") == 0) {
      exit_flag = 1;
      ret = pthread_cancel(thr);
      if (ret != 0)
        handle_error(ret, "pthread_cancel");
    }
  }

  free(detect);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

fail:
  free(detect);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

And here's the include mentioned at the top:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "file.h"

int find_prof(FILE *fd, int profile, fpos_t *prof_start, fpos_t *prof_end)
{
    int found = 0;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    char *check = NULL;

    buffer = malloc(2);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    check = malloc(2);
    if (check == NULL) {
        perror("memory error");
        goto fail;
    }
    sprintf(check, "#%d", profile);

    do {
        buffer[1] = fgetc(fd);
        if (strcmp(buffer, check) == 0 && found == 0) {
            fgetpos(fd, prof_start);
            found = 1;
        } else if (strcmp(buffer, check) == 0 && found == 1) {
            fgetpos(fd, prof_end);
            found = 2;
        } else {
            buffer[0] = buffer[1];
        }
    } while (found < 2);

    free(buffer);
    free(check);
    return 0;
    
fail:
    free(buffer);
    free(check);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: 'I would like the scanf in main and in the thread to work simultaneously'....can you break that down?  There is one input stream.  If two threads attempt to wait for input, one will be blocked out.

Comment: yeah, I decided to completely re-write this code because of that very reason

Comment: Wherever you need input, check for 'quit' and exit() if found.  It doesn't matter what thread, it does not matter about pthread_cancel(), it doesn't matter about freeing mallocs, just exit() and let your OS destroy everything.